# What is the small tied threads at edge of cloths or table cloths - called?

Tags: image-identification

What are the small tied threads at the edge of cloths or table cloths - called?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The whole thing is called a [fringe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fringe).

Answer (score 3):

The ones in the second photo are [tassels](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tassel).

Comment: A fringe of tassels?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I was hoping it could be called 'tassellated' but apparently not (yet).

Comment: This is the correct answer. The OP is asking about the threads on the edges. If the OP asked about all of the threads together as some design or structural element, then fringe would be appropriate.